# How to express symfony route placeholder not equal to somevalue

Tags: php, symfony

I have a symfony project where I need to manage dinamic subdomains and I've defined my route.yml file in the next way:

```
home:
    path: /
    host: "www.mydomain.com"
    defaults: {_controller: ApplicationBundle:Home:homePage}

subdomain_mainpage:
    path: /
    host: "{subdomain}.mydomain.com"
    defaults: {_controller: ApplicationBundle:Subdomain:showDescription}    

subdomain_otherpage:
    path: /anothersegment
    host: "{subdomain}.mydomain.com"
    defaults: {_controller: ApplicationBundle:Subdomain:showOtherSegment}       
    requirements:
        subdomain: !(www)
```

And the problem is that the "subdomain_otherpage" route doesn't work, I've tried some other ways of doing this but I couldn't make it work.  isn't it possible to do something like this? Isn't there a way of say that a placeholder can't be equal to any specific value??

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question thanks to this post http://librosweb.es/foro/pregunta/103/problema-con-requerimientos-en-definicion-de-una-ruta-symfony/.

First of all, you must wrap your regexp with quotes, and finally, for my case the regexp would be something like this `"^((?!www).)*$"`.

Comment: I think this expression not matches "www" as well as "abcwww" as well as "wwwabc" as well as "abcwwwabc". Any tip to match "exactly not www"?

Comment: @XaviMontero you're right. I think `^(?!www).*$` will do what want. Please give it a try

Answer (score 1):

As defined in the [Symfony Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html), you can set regular expression as placeholder requirement.

So try this `^(?!www).+` instead of this `!(www)`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm afraid that this doesn't work :S
Thanks anyway.